# How to create a module level global variable inside a function in python

Tags: python

I have a file called **functions**. In this file I have function with following code

```py
def converter(a):
    index = a.find(',')
    b = a[0:index]
    d = a[index + 1:]
    c1_1 = b.strip()
    c1_2 = d.strip()
```

Now I want to import that function into another file and then I want to apply some conditions on the c1_1 and c1_2 variables e.g

```py
from functions import converter
h = input("Type a command: ")
converter(h)
if c1_1 == 'a'
    print('something')
```

I have tried that approach but it does not work

Comment: `c1_1` is _local_ to your function. It cannot be accessed outside of it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate a will contain two values like 1 ,  something and the function will access and save both the values into c1_1 and c1_2 without any space

Comment: @Carcigenicate Now I have edited the code so take another look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but you should just return the values instead of relying on globals:

```
def converter(a):
    index = a.find(',')
    b = a[0:index]
    d = a[index + 1:]
    c1_1 = b.strip()
    c1_2 = d.strip()

    return c1_1, c1_2  # Return the values from the function 

. . . 

h = input("Type a command: ")
c1_1, c1_2 = converter(h)  # Then assign them here
if c1_1 == 'a' print('something'):
```